# Why can't load the data into mysql:

Tags: mysql, database, decimal, truncated

Mysql table `price` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `code` varchar(12) ,
  `date` date ,
  `open` decimal(8,2) ,
  `high` decimal(8,2) ,
  `low` decimal(8,2) ,
  `close` decimal(8,2) ,
  `amount` decimal(20,2) ,
  `volume` decimal(16,2) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the data.csv file which i want to load into tablbe price.

```
000046.XSHE,19940912,20.0,20.0,16.0,16.92,121262592.0,7043300
000046.XSHE,19940913,17.0,17.32,16.0,16.46,47195860.0,2810800
000046.XSHE,19940914,16.3,16.4,15.49,15.95,24762992.0,1558300
```

The max value for volume is `47195860.0` which is in the range of `decimal(20,2)`.

Load it with mysql `load` command.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'data.csv'
    INTO TABLE finance.price
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

An error info occurs:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)       
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

Show it to get the reason.

```
show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'volume' at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Number `121262592.0` is so lower than `decimal(20,2)`,why  `Data truncated for column 'volume' at row 1`,only one row loaded.

```
select * from price;
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
| code        | date       | open  | high  | low   | close | amount       | volume     |
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
| 000046.XSHE | 1994-09-12 | 20.00 | 20.00 | 16.00 | 16.92 | 121262592.00 | 7043300.00 |
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could be your input file does not have `\r\n` line termination.

Comment: DECIMAL(16,2) means that only two digits after decimal point will be stored. To avoid truncation you should use DECIMAL(20,7) for example. As for not loading into table, you may need to check the lines termination in your file (it might be \n instead of \r\n) and add 'OPTIONAL' word before ENCLOSED.

Comment: To piggy-back on Bill's question, can you replace `\r\n` with just `\n` and try again?

Comment: How many rows did you load?  If only one row, let's see it.  If many rows, then note that only one row had a problem; see if you can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'data.csv'
    INTO TABLE finance.price
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONAL  ENCLOSED BY '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n';
```